# What is the meaning of "langsam mal"?

Tags: word-usage, meaning-in-context

I found this sentence among the subtitles to a dubbed movie on DasErste TV:

> Dahin muss ich auch langsam mal zurück.

The "auch langsam mal" did not convey a meaning to me, so I [looked in DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/r/?corpus=untertitel&q=langsam%20mal) and found many examples of its use:

> Wir sollten mit den Entschuldigungen langsam mal aufhören.

> Du musst langsam mal lernen, deine Dinge zu regeln.

> Es wurde ja auch langsam mal Zeit, dass endlich einer...

> Hör langsam mal auf, Janet. -

The two-word phrase seems to act like a particle, but I cannot find it documented as such. What is its meaning and usage? Is auch associated or does it have an independent meaning?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Langsam mal* and in general the particle *mal* are just a way to "soften" the impact of a phrase for the sake of politeness. *Ich muss langsam mal los* is similar to saying "I should get going" instead of "I will leave now" or "I should go now".

Without *langsam mal*, the sentences feel just a bit more imperative/impatient (the following are not literal translations, but attempts to reflect the tone they evoke when I read them):

(without *lansam mal* / with *langsam mal*)

1. We should stop making excuses / it is about time we stop making excuses.
2. You should keep your *** together / You should start to learn to keep your *** together.
3. It was bloody time for... / It was about time that...
4. Stop, Janet / Please stop, Janet

I don't think the second option is *less* impatient, but it shows an attempt to remain polite.

Answer (score 6):

All sentences work without it nearly identically. the "langsam mal" adds a gist along the lines of "it is about time".

Comment: I've also heard "so langsam" - is there any difference in meaning between that and "langsam mal" or, indeed, just plain "langsam"?